# Ajax.BeginForm: What to return from controller to prevent page refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Run(Job job, HttpPostedFileBase productRequestFile, HttpPostedFileBase masterFile, string SignalRConnectionId)
{
    return View(job);
}
```

And this is the view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Run", "Job", null, new AjaxOptions(){ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "container" }, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"} ))
{

    <input type="file" name="masterFile" id="masterFile" class="btn btn-default" required />
    <input type="file" name="productRequestFile" id="productRequestFile" class="btn btn-default" required />
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Parameters, new { @class = "control form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Parameters)
    <input type="hidden" id="SignalRConnectionId" name="SignalRConnectionId" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <button id="StartButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary center-block">Start job</button>

}
```

Right now I'm returning `View(job)` but that causes a page refresh. If I return null, then the page goes blank. What can I return so that nothing happens to the page?

Comment: This has nothing to do with what's returned by your action. If I had to guess, you have a JavaScript error on page that is causing all JavaScript to stop functioning, including your AJAX, so the form is just working as a normal form.

Comment: Ok I will investigate this

Comment: Console shows no errors, just navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is that I was missing a reference to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax

Answer (score 0):

You need to give update target id in ajax options. Also, what Ajax form does is, it posts the form to the specified URL and then replaces(by default) all the content of UpdateTargetId div with content received as response, so in you case it is mandatory to return view, else, it will be blank.

Comment: I added this but it still refreshes the page, i'll update my post to reflect these changes